# Element background colour not supported in Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

The background colour of an element isn't covering the element it is sat on top of. I'm struggling to work out if this just isn't supported by Safari or a problem with my code.

The code below works fine on Chrome, Firefox etc, but not Safari, the background colour of the H1 element should hide the border of the below Container div.

HTML

```
<section class="section">
  <h1 class="introH1"><strong>What's the difference? Craft vs plant</strong></h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column">
      <p>I am trying to achieve the following in the most responsive, backward compatible way as possible. I appreciate that I may need to make a big compromise somewhere.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

SASS

```
.section
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    justify-content: center
    align-items: center
    padding: 4rem 1.5rem

    .introH1
        font-family: Monospace
        font-weight: bold
        text-transform: uppercase
        font-size: 1.875rem
        display: inline-block
        padding: 0 15px
        background-color: white
        margin-bottom: -1rem
        z-index: 2

    .container
        font-family: Monospace
        border: 3px solid #000
        text-align: center
        padding: 30px
        transform: perspective(10px) rotateX(-0.3deg)
        border-radius: 8px
        max-width: 800px
        box-sizing: border-box

        .column
            transform: perspective(10px) rotateX(0.3deg)
```

CODEPEN EXAMPLE
https://codepen.io/grantsmith/pen/YMVMgO

I am expecting to see something similar to the below image:

[image]

Comment: add screenshot current result on safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to .introH1

```
transform: translate3D(0,0,0.5px)
```

Your h1 element is under the container because of the perspective and rotateX property, container overlap h1 when rotates

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the background color in a rgb (rgba if you want transparency) format instead of using the name or code. For example :

```
background color : rgb(255, 255, 255);
```

or you can try this and see if it works

```
# @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{
#safari { background-color:#FFFF }
}
```

Comment: Hmm not sure why its happening but i made an edit with updated code. See if it helps

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because the z-index property works only on positionned elements, did you try to add a `position: relative` for the `.introH1` ?